# Regular expressions -- delimited

Tags: python, regex

I need to specify strings of the form

```
A
A,A
A,A,A
etc.
```

using Pythonic regular expression (`re` module). This example is simplified, `A` will be another long regular expression.

I could do it using `(A,)*A` but it seems to be redundant for me. The regular expression will be a part of some specification of a data format so it should be also human readable as much as possible. Is there any way how to write it shortly?

Expressions like

```
A,,A
A,A,
,A
```

should not be allowed.

Comment: don't know what you mean by redundant. May be you could could consider adding anchors `^(A,)*A$`

Comment: By regex `(A,)*A` is the best way i think! do you just want a regex solution?

Comment: What he means, is that `A` is a more complicated regex pattern itself, so he wants to avoid repeating it.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski i think he want a tools in regex that could handle delimiter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
^(?:A(?:,(?!$)|$))+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ0jK9/1)

Basically: match `A`, then either match a `,` not at the end of the string (`(?!$)`), or the end of the string.